# Magento Problem

Tags: magento

I am running a store on Magento.  For some reason the "Recently Viewed", "Related Items" and "Featured Items" blocks have all disappeared from my site.  They where definitely there yesterday so I'm not sure what's happened to them.

Featured Products is an extension I use and show on the home page using:

```
{{block type="featuredproducts/listing" template="inchoo/block_featured_products_main.phtml"}}
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reindexing my products fixed this.

system > index management

Answer (score 0):

Probably some Blocks that don't render. Check your /var/log/errors.log for clues (1) and remove the module if is giving you problems(2).

This one here is trying to load the Featuredproducts_Block_Listing class. Check if is there and if is not misspelled.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added any custom module to magento related to products like feature products or products on sale, if yes then just make it false from XML file /app/etc/modules/module.xml 
and then refresh or delete the cache and try again with front end.

If this will not work then just simply delete all cache, session and logs. and refreh the web page it will work.

Thanks 
Magento Development